# compare 2 lists from different syntaxes python

Tags: python, list, comparison

I am quite new to Python and I would like to compare each element from each list:

```
a=[]
b=[]


with open('dump.sql', 'r') as dump:
    for line in dump:
        if string1 in line:
                tail1 = line.split(string1)[1]
                for group1 in tail1.split("),("):
                        group1 = group1.replace("\'", "").replace("(", "").replace(")\n", "")
                        a.append(group1.split(",")[3].strip())
        if string2 in line:
                tail2 = line.split(string2)[1]
                for group2 in tail2.split("),("):
                        group2 = group2.replace("\'", "").replace("(","").replace(")\n","")
                        b.append(group2.split(",")[3].strip())
```

Since these 2 lists are in 2 separate "if", can be compared? And if yes, how?
I was wondering because if I am trying to print list a in second if, I don't get anything, so I suppose that should be done different than append the following part in the second if:

```
if(set(naptr)&set(naptra)):
       c.append(group2.split(",")[4].strip())
```

Best regards,
Dan

Comment: Have you tried anything?  a and b definitely exist outside of the if

Comment: a and b were defined there as empty lists which would be filled later with some values after iterate the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check for this Python module: [dfflib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html)

Here an example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 3, 4, 5]
diffGenerator = difflib.ndiff(list1, list2)
for diff in diffGenerator:
    print(diff)
```

The result would be:

```
  1
- 2
  3
+ 4
+ 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is good, but I would need something like: if difference exists between a and b => add something in list c.

Comment: You can use the result of ndiff function to create a third list no ?